# HttpResponseMessage Redirect to Private Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Developing an API using asp.net

Is it possible to redirect a user to a private azure blob storage? Can i do this using SAS keys or the azure blob SDK?

For example I want to do something like this:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri(bloburl);
return response;
```

Is it possible to access a private blob by putting a key in the URL? Obviously i dont want to put the master key though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to redirect a user to a private azure blob storage? Can
>   i do this using SAS keys or the azure blob SDK?

Yes, it is entirely possible to redirect a user to a private blob. You would need to create a `Shared Access Signature (SAS)` with at least `Read` permission and append that SAS token to your blob URL and do a redirect to that URL.

Your code would look something like this:

```
        var cred = new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        var account = new CloudStorageAccount(cred, true);
        var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = client.GetContainerReference("container-name");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("blob-name");
        var sasToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
        {
            Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)//Assuming you want the link to expire after 1 hour
        });
        var blobUrl = string.Format("{0}{1}", blob.Uri.AbsoluteUri, sasToken);
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri(bloburl);
        return response;
```

Comment: This is great thanks, just what I need. I didn't know that I could append a SAS key to a blob URL and reference it that way. I will report back after trying to implement.

Comment: Quick question: Is there any downside to creating a new SAS key for every blob request performance-wise? Also, since an application is using this API just to download a single image via the blob link, I assume it would be fine to have each link expire in 1 min? I imagine even a second consecutive request for the same blob will create a new SAS key..

Comment: `Is there any downside to creating a new SAS key for every blob request performance-wise? ` - Not that I can think of. Creation of SAS key doesn't make any network calls so there are no network or IO overhead.

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri - could you update your answer to use the latest API from Azure.Storage.Blobs, please? I believe that is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-user-delegation-sas-create-dotnet

Comment: @seankearon - Sure, let me take care of it over this weekend.

Comment: @GauravMantri - I've had a try myself today and you can see my approach in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/seankearon/cae6441bd2789fede6f0ca80a50fd790).